# Помогите с кодом или простенько объясните, чуть-чуть не разбираюсь :D

Tags: python, telebot

Когда в телеграме нажимаю на "Погода" и мне нужно ввести город или страну, я случайно ввёл не существующий город и код полетел, а как сделать так, чтобы когда пишешь не правильный город, тебе писалось, что выбран не существующий или же не правильный город.
Заранее спасибо за помощь.

```
import telebot
import random
import pyowm

from telebot import types
from random import choice
from pyowm.owm import OWM
from pyowm.utils.config import get_default_config

#Токен телеграмм-бота
TOKEN = 'token_bot'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

#Для погоды
owm = OWM('token_owm')
config_dict = get_default_config()
config_dict['language'] = 'ru'

#Для рандома
number = ['00', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '1st 12', '2nd 12', '3rd 12', '2 to 1 (верхний)', '2 to 1 (средний)', '2 to 1 (нижний)', '1 to 18', 'EVEN', 'На красное', 'На чёрное', 'ODD', '19 to 36']

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True)
    item1 = types.KeyboardButton('Random')
    item2 = types.KeyboardButton('Погода')

    markup.add(item1, item2)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет, {0.first_name}! Выбери две любые кнопки!' .format(message.from_user), reply_markup = markup)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_echo(message):
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        if message.text == 'Random':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выпадает' + "\n\n" + str(random.choice(number)))
        elif message.text == 'Погода':
            msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'В каком городе/стране?')
            bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, message_city)

def message_city(message):
    mgr = owm.weather_manager()
    observation = mgr.weather_at_place(message.text)
    w = observation.weather
    temp = w.temperature('celsius')["temp"]
    answer = f"В городе/стране, {message.text}, сейчас " + w.detailed_status + "\n"
    answer += "\nТемпература сейчас в районе " + str(temp) + "°. " + "\n\n"
    if temp < 10:
        answer += "Сейчас холодно! Оденьтесь теплее." 
    elif temp < 20:
        answer += "Сейчас температура в норме. Одевайте что пожелаете"
    else:
        answer += "Сейчас очень жарко! Советуем сходить на речку, соблюдая все правила!"

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, answer)


print('Программа запущена, можете писать боту.')

#Запуск бота
bot.polling(none_stop = True)

print('Программа остановлена!')
```

Comment: Ну как сделать  -  очень просто. Оформляешь обращение в конструкцию try-except  и по ошибке код не будет падать. Описано в любом учебнике по Python. Или предварительно сам пишеш код проверки на наличие соответствующего города и "пропускаешь" только те запросы, в которых город введен корректно.

Answer (score 0):

*См. изменения в строке `45`, решение через [try-except](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html)*

```py
from telebot import types
from random import choice
from pyowm.owm import OWM
from pyowm.utils.config import get_default_config

import telebot
import random
import pyowm


TOKEN = 'token_bot'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

#Для погоды
owm = OWM('token_owm')
config_dict = get_default_config()
config_dict['language'] = 'ru'

#Для рандома
number = ['00', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '1st 12', '2nd 12', '3rd 12', '2 to 1 (верхний)', '2 to 1 (средний)', '2 to 1 (нижний)', '1 to 18', 'EVEN', 'На красное', 'На чёрное', 'ODD', '19 to 36']

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True)
    item1 = types.KeyboardButton('Random')
    item2 = types.KeyboardButton('Погода')

    markup.add(item1, item2)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет, {0.first_name}! Выбери две любые кнопки!' .format(message.from_user), reply_markup = markup)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_echo(message):
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        if message.text == 'Random':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выпадает' + "\n\n" + str(random.choice(number)))
        elif message.text == 'Погода':
            msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'В каком городе/стране?')
            bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, message_city)

def message_city(message):
    mgr = owm.weather_manager()
    try:
        observation = mgr.weather_at_place(message.text)
    except pyowm.commons.exceptions.NotFoundError:
        answer = 'Простите, такого города похоже не существует :('
    else:
        w = observation.weather
        temp = w.temperature('celsius')["temp"]
        answer = f"В городе/стране, {message.text}, сейчас " + w.detailed_status + "\n"
        answer += "\nТемпература сейчас в районе " + str(temp) + "°. " + "\n\n"
        if temp < 10:
            answer += "Сейчас холодно! Оденьтесь теплее." 
        elif temp < 20:
            answer += "Сейчас температура в норме. Одевайте что пожелаете"
        else:
            answer += "Сейчас очень жарко! Советуем сходить на речку, соблюдая все правила!"

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, answer)


print('Программа запущена, можете писать боту.')

#Запуск бота
bot.polling(none_stop = True)

print('Программа остановлена!')
```